# Error while uploading large sized image to azure from a wp7 application

Tags: azure

I have to upload image with any size to azure cloud service. Locally I have made the changes in the respective configuration file and uploaded to the service successfully,to blob also.
Then i published the service. Now I am getting error while uploading images to this service.

"errorMessage":"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."  this is the error message ,which i am getting.    I have made these changes in the web.config of service  ,then i am able to upload succesfully.then i published the service .But to this service i am not able to upload with large size(which is greater than 200*200)

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="4800" maxRequestLength="2147483647"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment  aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <!--<standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" faultExceptionEnabled="true" >
        </standardEndpoint>-->
        <standardEndpoint name="" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" helpEnabled="true" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" faultExceptionEnabled="true" >
        </standardEndpoint>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding  transferMode="Streamed" closeTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647"></requestLimits>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

Comment: More details please. What's the error you're getting? Can you share the code you're using? This would help getting a solution to your problem.

Comment: "errorMessage":"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

Comment: You would need to share the code. There could be many reasons you will get 400 error.

Comment: any one please give me the solution as early as possible.

Comment: Hi Gaurav Mantri, Can you give me the solution?